# adding data to a table which has a pointer column parse.com

Tags: java, android, ios, parse-platform

i want to add some data to parse.com  table called -"stack". which has a mutliple columns and a pointer called  "User".
how can i add/update data to a table.

```
ParseObject flytagdata = new ParseObject("stack");
        flytagdata.put("Tag", sb.toString());
        flytagdata.put("Username", Constant.FB_USERNAME);
        flytagdata.put("UserFBId", Constant.FB_USERID);
        flytagdata.put("User", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());//pointer column data
    flytagdata.saveInBackground();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Parse.com pointers, you always pass the object itself instead of the objectId.

Like so:

```
ParseObject flytagdata = new ParseObject("stack");
    flytagdata.put("Tag", sb.toString());
    flytagdata.put("Username", Constant.FB_USERNAME);
    flytagdata.put("UserFBId", Constant.FB_USERID);
    flytagdata.put("User", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());//FIXED THIS LINE
flytagdata.saveInBackground();
```